# How to extract a substring from the beginning until '# '+ N characters

Tags: python

I have the string:

```
text1, text2 # 00035, other text
```

I need to get the substring from the beginning to # plus 7 characters.

```
# desired output:

text1, text2 # 00035
```

I have tried: `string.split('#', 7)[0])` but it doesn't work. It shows `text1, text2`

Comment: Why would you use `split()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```py
substring = string[:string.find('#') + 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your desired output shows that you want "from the beginning to # plus **6** characters".

If regex is also an option you can do:

```py
import re

pattern = r"^.*?#.{6}"
text = "text1, text2 # 00035, other text"
print(re.match(pattern, text).group())
```

output:

```
text1, text2 # 00035
```

The pattern says: from the beginning (`^`), get everything (`.*?` - non-greedy) to `#` plus 6 more characters (`.{6}`)

Answer (score 1):

A simple regular expression would do the trick:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "text1, text2 # 00035, other text"
>>> re.match(r"^.*#.{6}", s).group(0)
'text1, text2 # 00035'
```

A quick explanation:

1. `^` matches the start of the string.
2. `.*#` matches an arbitrary string ending with `#`
3. `.{6}` matches exactly 6 characters.

This assumes your string always has exactly one space following the `#` but before a 5-digit number appears. If either of those assumptions is false, the regular expression can be adjusted to accommodate it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.find()` to get the location of the `#` character within the string.

Then use a slice to select the portion of the string from the beginning up to that index plus eight.  (You said seven, but slice indexes do not include the last position, so we need to go one further.)

```
hash_index = string.find('#')
print(string[:hash_index+8])
```

Answer (score 0):

Print by index:

```
text = "text1, text2 # 00035 some other text with # "

l= [text.index(x) for x in text if x == '#'][0] + 8
print(text[:l])
```

Output:

```
text1, text2 # 00035
```

Answer (score 0):

Using original approach as in OP to show why is not a good idea

```
'#'.join([(blocks:=s.split('#', 1))[0], blocks[1][:7]])
```

Notice further that `str.split(char, 1)` is "equivalent" to `str.partition` (it returns a triple and not a tuple consisting of left, character and right part).

Also careful that solutions with `str.find` have side effects when the reference character `#` is missing because it returns `-1`. Use instead `str.index` is more robust because it raises an exception if the reference character is not found

```
s[:s.index('#') + 8]
#text1, text2 # 00035,
```

or if the reference character is not found

```
s[:s.index('?') + 8]
ValueError: substring not found
```